# Isomorphism of structures

Tags: logic

I am working on this problem :

Let $N$ be the $L_{0}$-structure $(\mathbb{N} ,<)$, where $\mathbb{N}$ is the set of non-negative integers, and let $M$ be the $V_{0}$-structure $({\mathbb{N}} - 0, <)$ (where $<$ is the usual inequality relation on $\mathbb{N}$. Show the following :

- (1) $M \cong N$
- (2) $M \equiv N$
- (3) $M$ is a substructure of $N$
- (4) $M$ is not an elementary substructure of $N$.

I know that I need to find an isomorphism between the structures in order to show (1)(is that enough?) and then (1) and (2) are equivalent, however I am struggling to do the whole proof in detail. Also (3) and (4) confused me.

Any help?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please, what are $\cong$, $\equiv$?

Comment: $ \cong$ denotes the isomorphism and $\equiv$ denotes the equivalance.

Comment: Then yes, all you need for (1) is to define an isomorphism and to _prove_ that it really is an isomorphism. It is usually almost trivial but you have to very carefully check each part of the definition. (1) and (2) are not equivalent, but (2) will follow if you prove (1). For (3) you again only need to check the definition. And some discussion concerning (4) you can find [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1357971).

Comment: Thank you!I did solve the (1), (2) and (4). However, I seem to struggle to prove (3). I have been trying to combine the definition of a substructure and the Downward Lowenheim-skolem theorem but without luck. Any hint on how to show this?

Comment: I repeat my last advice: for (3), check the definition of a substructure. Löwenheim-Skolem Theorem is not needed here.